# Making a multiple versions of a Object

Tags: c++, class, object, new-operator, ogre

I'm a student instructed to make a doodle jump replica with ogre3d.
I have a function which should make a panel on screen with a designated shape and location so now I wish to make a for loop that will make multiple (up to 10) and a random value that'll set each of them somewhere different on x,y,z.

```
void PlatformManager::CreatePanelDoodle( float x, float y, float z){

    
    Plane plane3(Vector3::UNIT_Y, 0);
    MeshManager::getSingleton().createPlane(
        "Paddle2", RGN_DEFAULT,
        plane3,
        20, 5, 20, 20,
        true,
        1, 5, 5,
        Vector3::UNIT_Z);
    Entity* groundEntity3 = scnMgr->createEntity("Paddle2");
    SceneNode* Paddlenode2 = scnMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();
    Paddlenode2->setPosition(Ogre::Vector3( x, y, z));
    Paddlenode2->attachObject(groundEntity3);
    groundEntity3->setCastShadows(false);
    
}
```

and this is for attempting to make multiple objects in random space

```
point plat[20];
    float pX;
    float pY;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        plat[i].x = rand() % 50;
        plat[i].y = rand() % 30;
        float pX = plat[i].x;
        float pY = plat[i].y;
    }
    

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        PlatformManager Panels = new PlatformManager->CreatePanelDoodle(pX, 0, pY);
    }
```

The problem is with the error in the for loop creation "No suitable constructor exists to convert void to "platform manager"

I've tried simply adding the  constructor into the for loop, and not using the loop at all. Whats going wrong?

Comment: _"PlatformManager Panels = new PlatformManager->CreatePanelDoodle(pX, 0, pY);"_ That makes no sense. `CreatePanelDoodle` is a member function. You can't call it with `new`. Its return type is `void`. What do you expect to happen here? How should this line create a new object?

Comment: Probably you want to just call the member function: `PlatformManager Panels = new PlatformManager->CreatePanelDoodle(pX, 0, pY);` ->  `PlatformManager->CreatePanelDoodle(pX, 0, pY);`

Comment: My hope was create the createpaneldoodle function and duplicate it multiple times. I wanted it to essentially be an object that I can instantiate as this code works when its not made into a separate function. I'm not sure how to make it into what I'm trying to do though.

Comment: `createpaneldoodle` is a function. What do you mean with _"duplicate it multiple times"_? _"I wanted it to essentially be an object that I can instantiate as this code works when its not made into a separate function."_ Why? What happens when you change `PlatformManager Panels = new PlatformManager->CreatePanelDoodle(pX, 0, pY);` to `PlatformManager->CreatePanelDoodle(pX, 0, pY);`? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Why do you have uninitialized variables `float pX;` and `float pY;` and different variables `float pX = plat[i].x;` resp. `float pY = plat[i].y;` in the loop? You are calling `PlatformManager->CreatePanelDoodle(pX, 0, pY);` with uninitialized values. Probably you want to replace your second code snippet with `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { PlatformManager->CreatePanelDoodle(rand() % 50, 0, rand() % 30); }`.

Comment: The contents of the function CreatePanelDoodle makes shapes on its own but on its own I'd have to statically create all the shapes I want.  My intention was to make all that code into something that can be replicated automatically at start and set in different places each time.  plat[i].y/x is integers but I needed them to be floats to work as coordinates so flat pX/pY was to convert them for use.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your second code snippet:

- You are using uninitialized variables `float pX;` and `float pY;`
- You are shadowing variables with `float pX = plat[i].x;` and `float pY = plat[i].y;`
- You are creating multiple random values but you are not using them
- You are trying to apply the `new` operator on a void function
- You are trying to store that result in a variable

You can solve the problems with

```
// Remove this block, you don't use the variables
/*
point plat[20]; // You don't use this array
float pX; // You use it uninitialized
float pY; // You use it uninitialized
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    plat[i].x = rand() % 50;
    plat[i].y = rand() % 30;
    float pX = plat[i].x; // You don't use this variable
    float pY = plat[i].y; // You don't use this variable
}
*/

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    PlatformManager->CreatePanelDoodle(static_cast<float>(rand() % 50), 0, static_cast<float>(rand() % 30));
}
```